# How do we tell user using phone or tablet?

Tags: android

I have an application which I wanted to have an interface that show 2 columns gridview on phone and 3 columns on tablet. How do I tell according to screen size that the user is using phone or tablet? What is the minimum size for phone and tablet?

Comment: Android has an excellent layout support, refer to "Supporting Multiple Screens" guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click Here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) for the screen support.

To Support multiple screen support, try [THIS](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)